# UTM Campaign Variable Tracking Through Google Analytics

Tags: variables, google-analytics, utm

I am trying to track UTM Campaign variables through Google Analytics.
I should be expecting thousands of hits through Analytics, but so far I only have 7
when filtering through "landing pages".

Does Google strip off the utm variable when tracking the URL?

How do you accurately track UTM Campaign variables (UTM campaign="Ship") through Google Analytics?

I have multiple UTM Campaigns going, but only have a few results showing on Analytics.

I also have a Button-Event set-up through Google Tag manager that only shows when the user has the UTM variable in the URL, But that also shows very few results on Analytics.

What am I missing?

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can literally be dozens of reasons for this.

First of all, you find your campaign data under "Acquisition > Campaigns > All Campaigns".

The UTM Parameters are set by you, "removed" by Google Analytics in the sense that you do not see them in the listed URLs anymore, but of course they still count towards what you see in the abovementioned section in GA.(otherwise no sense in tracking them in the first place)

Why do you assume there should be more hits on your campaigns? Do you have conflicting data from another source like Google Ads?

Comment: Thank you! I can now see all of my campaigns containing their parameters. I was looking in the wrong spot inside Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

You can find UTM parameters values ​​in `source / medium`.